# how to use a collection in a parameterized tagx file?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jspx

I'd like to convert a tag file to a tagx, but I can't find out how to re-write the attribute name/type declaration (last line):

TAG:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" prefix="tag"%>
<%@ taglib uri='http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions' prefix='fn'%>
<%@ tag import="myPackage.*"%>
<%@ attribute name="treeMap" type="java.util.Collection"%>  <!-- ##### this one #### -->
```

TAGX:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jsp:root
    version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
        xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
    xmlns:tag="/WEB-INF/tags"
    import="myPackage.*"
>
```

Can somebody tell me the appropirate syntax for `<%@ attribute name="treeMap" type="java.util.Collection"%>`? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should just be:

```
<jsp:directive.tag import="myPackage.*"/>
<jsp:directive.attribute name="treeMap" type="java.util.Collection"/>
```

By the way, it looks like you're actually referring to .tag and .tagx files...